# What do I verify within a client bearer token?

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, bearer-token

I've got service A, an [OAuth 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0) authentication server, and service B.

Service A has an API and trusts the authentication server.

Service B needs to call service A's API, and to do so it needs to include a client (i.e., non-user-specific) bearer token in the request header.

Aside from `client_id` and `sub` (which should be the same as `client_id`), what information from the bearer token does service A need to use to verify with the authentication server that service B is who it says it is, that the bearer token is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what information from the bearer token does service A need to use to verify with the auth server that service B is who it says it is, that the bearer token is valid?

In addition to `sub`, you should validate:

- That it is not expired.
- That the token issuer `iss` is the server that you trust.
- That the token is signed e.g. with RSA and signed by the issuers private certificate.

Common OAuth servers on the market can typically do these validations for you by using a http endpoint.

Comment: In other words, send it to the token introspection endpoint of the auth server and see what they say. :face_palm: